# Moments of probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-analysis, moment-problem

I am looking for a concrete random variable with skew $\gamma_1$ and kurtosis (not excess) $\gamma_2$, where
\begin{align}
\frac{\gamma_2}{2}-\frac{\gamma_1^2}{3} = 0. 
\end{align}
I alreagy tried mixtures of normal distributions with the density $f(x)= p \varphi(x)+(1-p)\varphi(x-\delta)$ with the standard normal density $\varphi$, but was not able to find a concrete distribution. Does such a random variable exist?

Comment: One approach is to play around with support and probabilities of discrete distributions. I played around with this a little and always got positive results for the difference. You might try using the logic of the usual inequality to attack this problem more mathematically; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)

Comment: Thanks for your responds! Meanwhile, I proofed under gerneal conditions, that there is no such random variable and that this value is always positive for non-trivial random variables. Thank you again for your will to help me with my problem.